# Is there any way to distinguish between if the screen was Small, Normal, Large, or X-Large without creating 4 files?

Tags: android, xml, android-xml, android-databinding

**fragment_categories.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:spanCount="2"
    tools:context=".fragments.CategoriesFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row_cateogry" />
```

I created 4 files of `fragment_categories.xml` using `available qualifiers` -> `Screen size` | [Look at UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jtHs.png)

- Small -> `app:spanCount="1"`
- Normal -> `app:spanCount="1"`
- Large -> `app:spanCount="2"`
- X-Large -> `app:spanCount="3"`

As you noticed I created 4 files of `fragment_categories.xml` only to change `app:spanCount`.

Is there any way to distinguish between if the screen was `Small`, `Normal`, `Large`, or `X-Large` without creating 4 files and without `Java`, Only in normal `XML` without `available qualifiers`?

I can do it in `Java` in one line to change `spanCount`, But I have another XML, and more complicated, So it is better to do it in the same `XML`

I'm using [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)

Answer (score 2):

I am using the library I mentioned below to create a responsive structure.

```
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
```

This library resizes XML automatically. It doesn't matter if the screen is big or small.

you need to **sdp** the lengths instead of **dp**. There is a ratio of 3 to 1 here. For example; If it's 100 dp you need to make an image 33sdp.

I may not have fully understood the question. If I misunderstood you can let me know.

Comment: I don't want to use an external library for this